# Release quality build with Starling with FlashDevelop on iPad

Tags: ios, air, flashdevelop, starling-framework

I compile my app using the fast compile option for iOS using staring and FlashDevelop.

Here is where I use the option 4:

[image]

Its said that the release quality is much faster, but how do I test it?

If I compile for the App Store, there is no way I can install the .ipa,
it can only run on the App Store for download, right?

Im confused...please send me some suggestions...

I want to test release quality version before sending to the review...

Mirza

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need ad-hoc version - this is release quality but can be installed locally without going thru app store.

And you can install the .ipa directly with itunes (just drag ipa file into itunes app window) but i wouldn't be surprised if Flash Develop can do that bit for you.